# Is there a way to change the lb-number output to a different version

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox2

I'm currently in the process of creating an about-us page, with a small gallery using lightbox2.

The language of the page will not be English, and due to design consistency and customer demand I'd like to change the printed **"Image x of y"** in the *"lb-dataContainer/lb-data/lb-number"*

Since it's a span created by the js I suppose my answer will be, of course, in there.

PS: I'd like to change the **"Image x of y"** format to an **"Image x / y"** format as well.

I'm very early into my web-dev career so please excuse any misunderstandings on my part.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [<>] snippet editor. Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this and many other questions about lighbox could be found on the examples page of the lightbox:
https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples

It says that you can use the option `albumLabel` to change the label - like this:

```
lightbox.option({
  albumLabel: "Image %1 / %2"
});
```